# XGBRegressor vs. xgboost.train huge speed difference?

Tags: machine-learning, python, decision-trees, xgboost, efficiency

If I train my model using the following code:

```
import xgboost as xg
params = {'max_depth':3,
'min_child_weight':10,
'learning_rate':0.3,
'subsample':0.5,
'colsample_bytree':0.6,
'obj':'reg:linear',
'n_estimators':1000,
'eta':0.3}

features = df[feature_columns]
target = df[target_columns]
dmatrix = xg.DMatrix(features.values,
                     target.values,
                     feature_names=features.columns.values)
clf = xg.train(params, dmatrix)
```

it finishes in about 1 minute.

If I train my model using the Sci-Kit learn method:

```
import xgboost as xg
max_depth = 3
min_child_weight = 10
subsample = 0.5
colsample_bytree = 0.6
objective = 'reg:linear'
num_estimators = 1000
learning_rate = 0.3

features = df[feature_columns]
target = df[target_columns]
clf = xg.XGBRegressor(max_depth=max_depth,
                min_child_weight=min_child_weight,
                subsample=subsample,
                colsample_bytree=colsample_bytree,
                objective=objective,
                n_estimators=num_estimators,
                learning_rate=learning_rate)
clf.fit(features, target)
```

it takes over 30 minutes.

I would think the underlying code is nearly exactly the same (i.e. `XGBRegressor` calls `xg.train`) - what's going on here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`xgboost.train` will ignore parameter `n_estimators`, while `xgboost.XGBRegressor` accepts. In `xgboost.train`, boosting iterations (i.e. `n_estimators`) is controlled by `num_boost_round`(default: 10)

In your case, the first code will do 10 iterations (by default), but the second one will do 1000 iterations. There won't be any big difference if you try to change `clf = xg.train(params, dmatrix)` into `clf = xg.train(params, dmatrix, 1000)`,

### References

http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.train

http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor