# XGBoost Fit vs Train

Tags: python, xgboost

I am trying to do a grid searching using the methodology that mentioned in this [post](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/). However, I found that `XGBClassifier().fit()` is using much more memory than `xgboost.train`. Does anyone know why? Is this related to sparse matrix?

Answer (score 5):

[XGBRegressor vs. xgboost.train huge speed difference?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17282/xgbregressor-vs-xgboost-train-huge-speed-difference) - see this answer, likely the defaults (num_boost_round=10 vs. n_estimators=100) are the cause of this.